# ServiceStack.net implementing CustomAuthProvider with additional parameters?

Tags: servicestack

Im trying to implement a CustomAuthProvider in ServiceStack.net. I need to extend past just the username/password with a 3rd parameter. (lets call it an apikey) I would also like this to accept the post as application/json

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        return false;

    var httpReq = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();

    string apiKey = httpReq.GetParam("apikey");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
        return false;

    var engine = Helpers.DbHelper.GetEngine();
    return engine.Account.ValidateApiKey(userName, password, apiKey);
}
```

and my payload looks like

```
{
    "UserName"="my.user", 
    "Password"="$thePassword!1", 
    "Apikey"="theapikey"
}
```

The username and password get to the TryAuthenticate() but the apikey is always null. The above works fine if I'm posting as a form.  I'm sure I've missed something or have a completely wrong idea of how to do this. I'm new to ServiceStack but have been look over examples and articles for the better part of a week. :( Any advice is appreciated.

**NOTE: I'm using Advance Rest Client Chrome extension as my test.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add your Apikey parameter as part of the Querystring (`http://localhost:1337/api/auth/credentials?Apikey=theapikey`)?

I believe the [AuthServce accepts an Auth object](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthService.cs#L24) so your Request's InputStream will be deserialized into the Auth object. This will ignore your `Apikey` parameter. I don't believe you can reread the InputStream of the Request in your TryAuthenticat override to pull out the `Apikey`.

If you add ApiKey to the querystring you can pull it out in your TryAuthenticate override.

```
var req = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
var apiKey = req.QueryString["Apikey"];
```

You could also write your own Service that accepts an object with `UserName, Password and ApiKey`. You could  validate the Apikey and then call into the AuthService only passing in UserName and Password parameters.